# optimize query when i run it it took more time

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT id, status, category, logourl, businessname, slug
    , address2, city, state, country, zipcode, latitude
    , longitude, isclaimed
FROM (SELECT distance(33.8730134379712132, -117.5613892553118574, longitude , latitude) AS distance
        , id, status, category, logourl, businessname, slug
        , address2, city, state, country, zipcode, latitude
        , longitude, isclaimed
        , rank() over (partition by businessname, city, category order by id desc) as rank
       from hmgravy_yelpbusiness ) as dt
where rank = 1 AND slug != ''
AND status = True
AND isclaimed!='Y'
AND (longitude <= 34.01794097420309 AND longitude >= 33.72808590173933
   AND ABS(latitude) <= 117.75476524524271 AND ABS(latitude) >= 117.368013265381)
AND distance <= 10
AND category = 'General Contractors'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LOWER(city) = 'corona' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
 , distance ASC, city ASC, logourl DESC
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
  ;
```

Comment: please format your post

Comment: Please also provide database details - we can't help optimise a query when we know pretty much nothing about your database

Comment: The database is postgres.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your problem so people understand it more?

Comment: When I say "please provide database details" I mean, what are your table structures? Roughly how many records are in these tables? What indexes do you have on these tables? What version of Postgres ( `select version();` )? Is autovacuum running?

Comment: And also is better to provide result of EXPLAIN (ANALYZED,BUFFER).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, status, category, logourl, businessname, slug, address2, city, state, country, zipcode, latitude, longitude, isclaimed 
FROM (SELECT distance(33.8730134379712132, -117.5613892553118574,longitude , latitude) 
AS distance, id, status, category, logourl, businessname, slug, address2, city, state, country, zipcode, latitude, longitude, isclaimed, 
rank() over (partition by businessname, city, category order by id desc) 
AS rank
FROM hmgravy_yelpbusiness ) as dt where rank = 1 
AND slug != '' 
AND status = True
AND isclaimed!='Y' 
AND (longitude <= 34.01794097420309 
AND longitude >= 33.72808590173933 
AND ABS(latitude) <= 117.75476524524271 
AND ABS(latitude) >= 117.368013265381) 
AND distance <= 10 
AND category = 'General Contractors' 
ORDER
BY CASE WHEN LOWER(city) = 'corona' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END , distance ASC, city ASC, logourl DESC 
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

**Update:**  Just formatted